# How to get a list of _id names in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I would like to create a list of _id names e.g. `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']` with PyMongo out of this query:

```
> db.users.find({},{ "_id":1} ).limit(10)
{ "_id" : "0" }
{ "_id" : "1" }
{ "_id" : "2" }
{ "_id" : "3" }
{ "_id" : "4" }
{ "_id" : "5" }
{ "_id" : "6" }
{ "_id" : "7" }
{ "_id" : "8" }
{ "_id" : "9" }
```

However, the following code does not produces any results:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = MongoClient()
    sDB = db.test.users
    for u in list(sDB.users.find({}, {"_id": 1}).limit(10)):
        print "!!!", u
```

Why is the above list empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've referenced into `users` twice, so it's actually looking in the `users.users` collection.

This should work (you don't need the `list` call either):

```
db = MongoClient()
users = db.test.users
for u in users.find({}, {"_id": 1}).limit(10):
    print "!!!", u
```